# Windows IoT Core does not boot after impoper shutdown, flashes 7 times

Tags: raspberry-pi, boot, windowsiot

I have installed Windows 10 IoT Core 10.0.10586.0 on Raspberry PI 2. One thing that bothers me is that if power has been disconnected *during the boot process* and restored the PI does not boot. It blinks 7 times with Act LED, pauses and blinks again.

If I cycle power again, it boots correctly.

The device I'm creating may loose power and I expect Windows to start reliably. Is that behavior expected? Is there a solution / workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Shutting down Iot by turning off the power is essentially the same as unplugging your PC while it's running. In general it's risky and can cause corruption.

I believe the kind of control you want is only available from the commercial version right now. https://www.windowsforiotdevices.com/. That version has the ability to control which features you have included in your image and you have more control over the boot process and possibly also the SDCARD virtual disk write cache. You should be able to develop a more robust boot booting experience with that version. That all said, I do believe it's in Microsoft's best interest is to improve the reliability for IoT devices running Windows IoT. Since the first version last year there have been major improvements and I'm quite sure that there are more major improvement on the horizon. Windows IoT is relatively new compared to Raspian and other IoT OS's, so they have to make it reliable in order for it to be viable for anything other than educational purposes.